# How to get UINavigationItem width in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationitem, iboutlet

I am trying to get the width of the **UINavigationItem** in swift 4.

I tried:

1. I took the IBOutlet of the navigation item, but i see the warning: Value of type 'UINavigationItem' has no member 'frame'

   `self.backNavItem.frame.size.width`
2. I tried getting the width from navigation item but it didn't work

`let item = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
    let btnView = [item, value(forKey: "view")]
    let backButtonWidth = btnView.frame.size.width`

your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The UINavigationItem itself does not have any visual UI representation it just holds the details of the UI elements that a UINavigationController will use to populate it's UINavigationBar.  It's the UINavigationBar itself that has a frame.

Comment: why can't you give the IBOutlet to the button inside navigation item?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Yes your right, but there should be some way to figure out its width.

Comment: The UINavigationItem has no width.  All it does it provide the elements that the UINavigationController uses to determine the layout of it's UINavigationBar.  In order to get any kind of width you have to go to the UINavigationBar itself.

Comment: @VincentJoy What difference it makes ? still we will not be able to know its width.